# Multiline property of XtraGrid gridview column

Tags: c#-4.0, devexpress, xtragrid

I am binding a dataset to a XtraGrid gridview. I need to set one of the columns in the gridview to multiline. Could someone tell me how to set the property of a particular column in the grid to multiline.

Note: The DevExpress XtraGrid is from a third party dll.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show multi-line text in the XtraGrid utilize the [RepositoryItemMemoEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsMemoEdittopic) as an in-place editor in the grid. To adjust the row height automatically and display the content of cells, enable the [OptionsView.RowAutoHeight](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_RowAutoHeighttopic) option.

Comment: can we add scroll bar in a cell in the data grid?

Comment: You can set the RowHeight explicitly and scrollbar will be shown when the text exceed this height while editing